# No popup asking permission only on iOS, permission not determined, react-native-community/geolocation

Tags: react-native

I use react-native-community/geolocation to check user location. Everything works fine only in android. Location is use on start, so in android popup message is promted at start.
On iOS I have no popup asking permission.

To check permission I installed react-native-location i my test code returns 'notDetermined'

My code:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import RNLocation, {getCurrentPermission} from 'react-native-location';
...
if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
            Geolocation.requestAuthorization(); 
            const locationConfig = {authorizationLevel: "whenInUse"}; //try "always" too
            Geolocation.setRNConfiguration(locationConfig);
}
...
RNLocation.configure({
  distanceFilter: 1.0
});

RNLocation.getCurrentPermission().then(curPerr => {
           console.log(curPerr); //result notDetermined
});

RNLocation.requestPermission({
  ios: "whenInUse",
  android: {
    detail: "coarse"
  }
}).then(granted => {

    console.log('granted: ', granted); //it doesn't show it in the console!

    if (granted) {
        this.locationSubscription = RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates(locations => {
        })
    }
  })
```

Info.plist

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We use your location...</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We use your location...</string>    
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription </key>
    <string>We use your location...</string>
...
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did write Info.plist file just like you and have met the same case.
In my case, I removed the first and second options and remains only the third option, then it was worked.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We use your location...</string>
```

The ios version is 12.
I'm not sure well, but this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450080/ios-11-location-permission-with-three-options-from-the-beginning) is related to your questions and may help.